# How do Strongloop process manager versions and rollback functionality work

Tags: deployment, loopbackjs, strongloop

This evening I noticed my staging server ran out of disk space.

When investigating I saw each time I deploy my loopback-js app with strongloop process manager, it installs a brand new app in a new folder.

After deploying 20 times I have 20 versions, which each take up 140 Mb.

I assume those folders make it easy to switch between versions, but I cannot figure out how I should do that with strong-pm and if I can specify how many versions should be saved, etc...

**How do these versions, rollback-functionality work in strongloop-process manager and where can i find documentation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there is no true "rollback" mechanism in strong-pm. The closest you can get is to deploy a previously deployed git commit, which will re-use the previous deployment that matches that commit's hash.